# Display more than 5 messages in TileUpdater

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I use in my application ScheduledTileNotifications and push 10 until 20 messages in the TileUpdateManager. But on the metro there are only 5 messages active. What can I do to display more than 5 notifications in the metro-Tile?

```
string tileXmlString = "<tile>"
       + "<visual>"
       + "<binding template='TileWideSmallImageAndText03' branding='name'>"
       + "<image id='1' src='ms-appx:///Assets/icons/cube_for_kachel.png'/>"
       + "<text id='1'>" + longSubject + "\n" + message.title + "</text>"
       + "</binding>"
       + "<binding template='TileSquareText04' branding='name'>"
       + "<text id='1'>" + shortSubject + "\n" + message.title + "</text>"
       + "</binding>"
       + "</visual>"
       + "</tile>";

XmlDocument tileXml = new XmlDocument();
tileXml.LoadXml(tileXmlString);
ScheduledTileNotification sceduleNotification = new ScheduledTileNotification(tileXml, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(15));
TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().EnableNotificationQueue(true);
TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().AddToSchedule(sceduleNotification);
```

---

When I set the **EnableNotificationQueue** to true, five of my notification run in a circle. When I set it to false, my notification don´t run in a circle. But I have 10 until 20 Notifications, which should run in a circle. Do you think it is possible.

When I use the **AddToSchedule** method an push 10 Notifications, each notification will show for one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to the use of the **EnableNotificationQueue** method. In fact, as you can read at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.tileupdater.enablenotificationqueue:

> When queuing is enabled, a maximum of five tile notifications can
>   automatically cycle on the tile.

Try to pass **false** to this method.

According to the documentation, you can schedule up to 4096 notifications. Reref to http://hansstan.wordpress.com/2012/09/02/windows-8-advanced-tile-badge-topics/ for a working example.